# autoMapper Related Error , at lambda_method19(Closure , Head , Head , ResolutionContext )

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

plz Help  Regards Auto Mapper

Profile page --

```
 CreateMap<ReqPay,ReqPayDb>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ReqpayID,opt => opt.Ignore() )
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Etc,opt => opt.Ignore() )
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Head, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Head))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Txn, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Txn))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Merchant, opt => opt.MapFrom(Src => Src.Merchant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Meta, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Meta))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Vehicle, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Vehicle))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Payer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Payer))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Payee, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Payee))
            ;
```

---

Reqpay is our DTO Class

```
namespace Dtos.ReqPay
{
     [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReqPay")]
 
    public class ReqPay
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Head")]
        public Head Head { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Txn")]
        public Txn Txn { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Merchant")]
        public Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Meta")]
        public Meta Meta { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Vehicle")]
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Payer")]
        public Payer Payer { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Payee")]
        public Payee Payee { get; set; }
        
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Signature", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public Signature Signature { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "etc", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Etc { get; set; }
        
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Head")]
    public  class Head
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ver")]
        public string Ver { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ts")]
        public string Ts { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orgId")]
        public string OrgId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "msgId")]
        public string MsgId { get; set; }
 
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tag")]
    public class Tag
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Meta")]
    public class Meta
    {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tag")]
        public List<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Score")]
    public class Score
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "provider")]
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RiskScores")]
    public class RiskScores
    {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Score")]
        public Score Score { get; set; }
    }
 
    public partial  class Txn
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "RiskScores")]
        public RiskScores RiskScores { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "note")]
        public string Note { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "refId")]
        public string RefId { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "refUrl")]
        public string RefUrl { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ts")]
        public string Ts { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orgTxnId")]
        public string OrgTxnId { get; set; }
 
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Lane")]
    public class Lane
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "direction")]
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "readerId")]
        public string ReaderId { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Parking")]
    public class Parking
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "floor")]
        public string Floor { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "zone")]
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "slotId")]
        public string SlotId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "readerId")]
        public string ReaderId { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReaderVerificationResult")]
    public class ReaderVerificationResult
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tsRead")]
        public string TsRead { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "signData")]
        public string SignData { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "signAuth")]
        public string SignAuth { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "epcVerified")]
        public string EpcVerified { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "procRestrictionResult")]
        public string ProcRestrictionResult { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "vehicleAuth")]
        public string VehicleAuth { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "publicKeyCVV")]
        public string PublicKeyCVV { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "txnCounter")]
        public string TxnCounter { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "txnStatus")]
        public string TxnStatus { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Merchant")]
    public class Merchant
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lane")]
        public Lane Lane { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Parking")]
        public Parking Parking { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReaderVerificationResult")]
        public ReaderVerificationResult ReaderVerificationResult { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "geoCode")]
        public string GeoCode { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "subtype")]
        public string Subtype { get; set; }
    }
 
 
    public  class Detail
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
 
 
    public  class VehicleDetails
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Detail")]
        public List<Detail> Detail { get; set; }
    }
 
 
    public partial class Vehicle
    {
        
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tagId")]
        public string TagId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TID")]
        public string TID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "avc")]
        public string Avc { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wim")]
        public string Wim { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VehicleDetails")]
        public VehicleDetails VehicleDetails { get; set; }
 
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Amount")]
    public class Amount
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "curr")]
        public string Curr { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Payer")]
    public class Payer
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Amount")]
        public Amount Amount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "addr")]
        public string Addr { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Payee")]
    public class Payee
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "addr")]
        public string Addr { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Signature", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public  class Signature
    {
        
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignedInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public SignedInfo SignedInfo { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignatureValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public string SignatureValue { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "KeyInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public KeyInfo KeyInfo { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }
    
     [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "SignedInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public class SignedInfo
    {
        
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CanonicalizationMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public CanonicalizationMethod CanonicalizationMethod { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignatureMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public SignatureMethod SignatureMethod { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Reference", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public Reference Reference { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "CanonicalizationMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public class CanonicalizationMethod
    {
       
       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "SignatureMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public class SignatureMethod
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Reference", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public class Reference
    {
        
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Transforms", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public Transforms Transforms { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DigestMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public DigestMethod DigestMethod { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DigestValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public string DigestValue { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "URI")]
        public string URI { get; set; }
    }
 
     [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Transforms", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public class Transforms
    {
 
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Transform", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public Transform Transform { get; set; }
    }
    public class Transform
    {
        
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "DigestMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public class DigestMethod
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Algorithm")]
        public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "KeyInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public  class KeyInfo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "X509Data", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public X509Data X509Data { get; set; }
    }
 
     [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "X509Data", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public class X509Data
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "X509SubjectName", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public string X509SubjectName { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "X509Certificate", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
        public string X509Certificate { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```

---

Reqpaydb is for Database class

```
namespace ModelRequest
{
    //[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReqPay", Namespace = "http://npci.org/etc/schema/")]
   [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReqPay")]
    public class ReqPayDb
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReqpayID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Head")]
        public Head Head { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Txn")]
        public Txn Txn { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Merchant")]
        public Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Meta")]
        public Meta Meta { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Vehicle")]
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Payer")]
        public Payer Payer { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Payee")]
        public Payee Payee { get; set; }
        
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "etc", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Etc { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Head")]
    public  class Head
    {
        [Key]
        public int HeadID { get; set; } 
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ver")]
        public string Ver { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ts")]
        public string Ts { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orgId")]
        public string OrgId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "msgId")]
        public string MsgId { get; set; }
 
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tag")]
    public class Tag
    {
        [Key]
        public int TagID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Meta")]
    public class Meta
    {
        [Key]
        public int MetaID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tag")]
        public List<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Score")]
    public class Score
    {
        [Key]
        public int ScoreID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "provider")]
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RiskScores")]
    public class RiskScores
    {
        [Key]
        public int RiskScorID { get; set; } 
        
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Score")]
        public Score Score { get; set; }
    }
 
    public partial  class Txn
    {
        [Key]
        public int TxnID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "RiskScores")]
        public RiskScores RiskScores { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "note")]
        public string Note { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "refId")]
        public string RefId { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "refUrl")]
        public string RefUrl { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ts")]
        public string Ts { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orgTxnId")]
        public string OrgTxnId { get; set; }
 
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Lane")]
    public class Lane
    {
       [Key]
       public int LaneID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "direction")]
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "readerId")]
        public string ReaderId { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Parking")]
    public class Parking
    {
       [Key]
       public int ParkingID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "floor")]
        public string Floor { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "zone")]
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "slotId")]
        public string SlotId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "readerId")]
        public string ReaderId { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReaderVerificationResult")]
    public class ReaderVerificationResult
    {
        [Key]
        public int RederVerResID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tsRead")]
        public string TsRead { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "signData")]
        public string SignData { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "signAuth")]
        public string SignAuth { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "epcVerified")]
        public string EpcVerified { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "procRestrictionResult")]
        public string ProcRestrictionResult { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "vehicleAuth")]
        public string VehicleAuth { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "publicKeyCVV")]
        public string PublicKeyCVV { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "txnCounter")]
        public string TxnCounter { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "txnStatus")]
        public string TxnStatus { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Merchant")]
    public class Merchant
    {
        [Key]
        public int MerchantID { get; set; } 
        
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lane")]
        public Lane Lane { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Parking")]
        public Parking Parking { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReaderVerificationResult")]
        public ReaderVerificationResult ReaderVerificationResult { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "geoCode")]
        public string GeoCode { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "subtype")]
        public string Subtype { get; set; }
    }
 
 
    public  class Detail
    {
        [Key]   
        public int DetailID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
 
 
    public  class VehicleDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int VehicleDetailsID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Detail")]
        public List<Detail> Detail { get; set; }
    }
 
 
    public partial class Vehicle
    {
        [Key]
        public int VehicleID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tagId")]
        public string TagId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TID")]
        public string TID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "avc")]
        public string Avc { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wim")]
        public string Wim { get; set; }
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VehicleDetails")]
        public VehicleDetails VehicleDetails { get; set; }
 
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Amount")]
    public class Amount
    {
        [Key]
        public int AmtId { get; set; } 
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "curr")]
        public string Curr { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Payer")]
    public class Payer
    {
        [Key]
        public int PayerID { get; set; }    
 
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Amount")]
        public Amount Amount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "addr")]
        public string Addr { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
 
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Payee")]
    public class Payee
    {
        [Key]
        public int PayeeID { get; set; }
 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "addr")]
        public string Addr { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

On Controller
{
var teststr = "";

```
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var textFromBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            teststr = textFromBody;
        }

        ReqPay ReqReturn = new ReqPay();
        // if pass this value as return then json as output
        ReqReturn = DeserializeXML.Deserialize<ReqPay>(teststr, "etc:ReqPay", "ReqPay");

        // this is for  Serialize XML, result into string , output as xml 
        var nextstr1 = SerializeXML.XmlSerialize<ReqPay>(ReqReturn, "ReqPay", "etc:ReqPay");
        ReqPayDb reqPayEntry = _mapper.Map<ReqPayDb>(ReqReturn);
```

### }

Error  on postman  500 Internal Error

AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:

ReqPay -> ReqPayDb

Dtos.ReqPay.ReqPay -> ModelRequest.ReqPayDb

Type Map configuration:

ReqPay -> ReqPayDb

Dtos.ReqPay.ReqPay -> ModelRequest.ReqPayDb

Destination Member:

Head

---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:

Head -> Head

Dtos.ReqPay.Head -> ModelRequest.Head

at lambda_method19(Closure , Head , Head , ResolutionContext )

at lambda_method18(Closure , Object , ReqPayDb , ResolutionContext )

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at lambda_method18(Closure , Object , ReqPayDb , ResolutionContext )

at Controllers.ReqPayController.ReqPay() in D:\Comvision\Acquirer_net5\Controllers\ReqPayController.cs:line 80

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS

=======

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Type: application/xml

Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Host: localhost:5001

User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.0

Content-Length: 4754

Postman-Token: 61ebaba3-ec84-4ad8-ae44-79add3b24ecc

Plz Help me

What is going wrong,

or suggests on email anandtri@gmail.com

Thanks in Advance

Comment: wowa wiwa! could you perhaps reformat this post? its a bit hard to read.

Comment: @Anand: you have to provide more context to the problem, otherwise it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a Map from your Head DTO to your Head DbModel

```
CreateMap<Dtos.ReqPay.Head,ModelRequest.Head>();
```